# ¿Detectar si el contenido de un EditText fue cambiado por el usuario o programáticamente?

Tags: java, android

Necesito detectar el cambio del contenido de un `EditText` pero diferenciando si ha sido el usuario o bien el programa.

```
mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        //diferenciar quien ha sido
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo he solucionado usando la propiedad `tag` de los componentes.

Si no existe valor a la propiedad `tag` el cambio ha sido realizado por el usuario y cuando es modificado para el programa, especificar un valor en el `tag`.

Luego al interceptar el cambio del texto, se comprueba el valor del `tag` para diferenciar quien ha sido.

```
mEditText.setTag("app");
mEditText.setText("contenido modificado"); //justo aquí se intercepta
mEditText.setTag(null);

mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        //diferenciar quien ha sido
        if (mEditText.getTag() == null) {
           //Modificado por el usuario
        } else {
           //Modificado por el programa
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: Excelente, no había requerido de esto y desconocía esta información.